# Función para puntuar composición gramatical

Tags: python, python-3.x

Dispongo de la siguiente lista de listas:

```
lista = [[('PRP', 1), ('VBG', 1), ('NNP', 1)],
         [('PRP', 2), ('VBG', 2), ('CONJ', 1), ('VBZ', 1)]]
```

Deseo construir una función que asigne puntos a cada lista (composición de una oración), dependiendo del número de verbos que tenga.

Si el número de verbos (VBG + VBZ) es menor de 2, asignar 1 puntos.
Si el número de verbos (VBG + VBZ) es igual o mayor de 2, asignaro 2 puntos.

Gracias por las pistas.

Comment: Hola pyring, no queda claro como asignas puntuación. Creo que te has confundido al expresarlo ya que asignas 2 puntos siempre :). Te recomiendo siempre incluir algo de lo intentado, en caso contrario puede que la pregunta no sea bien recibida en el sitio.

Comment: Es verdad, vaya cabeza. Corregido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones, si quieres una lista con las puntuaciones puedes usar  listas por compresión junto `sum` y la sintaxis del operador ternario:

```
def puntuacion(lista):         
    return [2 if sum(c[1] for c in frase if c[0] in {'VBZ', 'VBG'}) >= 2 else 1
                for frase in lista]
```

`sum(c[1] for c in frase if c[0] in {'VBZ', 'VBG'})` retorna la suma del segundo elemento de cada tupla si el primero es 'VBZ' o 'VBG', es decir, la suma de verbos.
La salida para tu ejemplo es:

```
puntos = puntuación(lista)
[1, 2]
```

---

Si vas a hacer más consultas de este tipo te sugiero convertir las listas de tuplas en diccionarios por comodidad y eficiencia:

```
>>> frases = [dict(frase) for frase in lista]
```

ahora puedes acceder al número de cada tipo gramatical mediante clave. Por ejemplo, el número de verbos en la segunda frase es:

```
>>> frases[1].get('VBZ', 0) + frases[1].get('VBG', 0)
3
```

Comment: Interesante este último comentario. He compilado la idea general del programa en otra pregunta. Veo que a veces hay muchas maneras de hacer lo mismo, pero algunas condenan posibilidades y otras abren puertas... esto de programar es un mundo.

Comment: FJSevilla: hay una discusión sobre las etiquetas de Python en la que sería interesante que pudieras participar, como gurú del lenguaje :) [Fusionar python-3.x con python (otra vez)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2890/83)